# Using duplicated as a filter with dplyr by the number of inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I'am currently using the following line of code to filter a dataframe based on two variables and two conditions.

```
df %>% filter(v1 %in% c('value1', 'value2')) %>% 
        filter(v2 %in% v2[duplicated(v2)])
```

In my dataset, v1 consists of multiple tags and v2 consists of user_ids. A single user_id in v2 can have multiple tags (in v1) looking as follows:

```
v1      v2 
html    piet
c#      piet 
c#      klaas
html    klaas
python  klaas
```

when I use the line of code that I'm currently working with it will do the job just fine when I use just two values e.g. `df %>% filter(v1 %in% c('c#', 'html')) %>% filter(v2 %in% v2[duplicated(v2)])` will nicely return:

```
v1      v2 
html    piet
c#      piet 
c#      klaas
html    klaas
```

But when using three values in the first filter e.g. `df %>% filter(v1 %in% c('c#', 'html', 'python')) %>% filter(v2 %in% v2[duplicated(v2)])` it also returns the values of piet while I actually want it to return only the values of klaas as follows:

```
v1      v2 
c#      klaas
html    klaas
python  klaas
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Why shouldn't it return piet? You're filtering in rows that have either c#, html or python in them, and then filtering out rows that have only one instance of v2. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering out cases where the `v1` for any specific row does not equal any of the three strings. This is not what you're trying to achieve - you want to only preserve `v2` groups where all three strings are represented in `v1`. The way to achieve that is:

```
df %>% group_by(v2) %>% 
  filter(all(c('c#', 'html', 'python') %in% v1))
```

First we group by v2, then we filter these groups so that only those where `all` three strings are included `%in%` the vector of `v1`s of that group.

Note that the order for the `%in%` command is reversed compared to your code, that's because we don't care if `v1` has other cases, we care if all three cases are represented in `v1` - if we also want to exclude all cases where `v1` isn't one of these three, you should have both directions, as in the following example:

```
df<-rbind(df,data.frame(v1="moose",v2="klaas"))
df %>% group_by(v2) %>% 
  filter(all(c('c#', 'html', 'python') %in% v1), v1 %in% c('c#', 'html', 'python'))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   v2 [1]
  v1     v2   
  <fct>  <fct>
1 c#     klaas
2 html   klaas
3 python klaas
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.